# SQL cluster Server connection pool on Tomcat

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling

i have been trying to configure a webapp my company bought based on MS SQL, our setup is:

2x Nodes for the cluster

1x Domain Controller

1x external NAS storage

OS is WS2016
and installed SQL 2014 cluster rule for both Nodes for high availability

we make it works with the standalone SQL installation as a test and it works but it's very frustrating to make it work with the SQL cluster server

here is my context configuration:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/App1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="5000"
    username="username" password="password" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLclstsrv:1433;DatabaseName=databasename;"/>

<Resource name="jdbc/App1wh" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="5000"
    username="username" password="password" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLclstsrv:1433;DatabaseName=databasename;"/>
```

i really need help to configure it with the cluster SQL server.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure it out, my resource data are correct but the it failed to login even i tested the login name and password just recreated it again and it worked for me!!!